# Standard bit representation of uint64_t?

Tags: int, standards, uint64

I know that for floating point numbers IEEE has a standard representation format - IEEE 754. Is there a standard representation for uint64_t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unsigned integer therefore there is no signed bit, and simply there should be a flat bit structure such that

```
value = bit_0 * 2^0 + bit_1 * 2^1 + bit_2 * 2^2 +  . . .  + bit_(n-1) * 2^(n-1)
value = sigma (i=0 to n-1) {bit_i * 2^i}
```